# Failure when exporting dataset with real-valued cells

Tags: bugs, export, dataset

Consider the following dataset:

```
dat = Dataset[<| "A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>];
ExportString[dat, "CSV"]
```

It exports perfectly, with the expected result:

```
(* "A",1
   "B",2 *)
```

The above also works fine if the cells of the dataset are strings:

```
dat = Dataset[<| "A" -> "1", "B" -> "2"|>];
```

However, if the cells are reals (only one of them seems to be enough), then

```
dat = Dataset[<| "A" -> 1.0, "B"-> 2.0 |>];
ExportString[dat, "CSV"]
```

returns `$Failed`, with the following message:

```
Dataset::exportfail: Dataset of the given form could not be exported as format "CSV".
```

The same issue appears when using `Export` rather than `ExportString`. I am currently using `ToString` to convert all cells to strings before exporting. Is this a bug?

I am using OS X, Mathematica version 11.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 11.0.0.0, a detailed examination of the traced execution of `ExportString[dat, "CSV"]` reveals that the error occurs due to a bug in the internal function `` Dataset`ImportExport`PackagePrivate`txt ``.

This function is supposed to convert values of various types to strings.  But we find that it has problems with real numbers:

```
Dataset;

Dataset`ImportExport`PackagePrivate`txt[1]
(* 1 *)

Dataset`ImportExport`PackagePrivate`txt[1.0]
(* GeneralUtilities`TextString`PackagePrivate`fmtReal[1., 10] *)
```

We can inspect the definitions of `txt`, looking for the definition applicable for real numbers:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[Dataset`ImportExport`PackagePrivate`txt]

(*
   ...
   txt[r_Real | r_Rational] := fmtReal[r, 10];
   ...
*)
```

However, if we look at the definitions of `fmtReal`, we find that the only definition expects one argument, not two:

```
PrintDefinitions[GeneralUtilities`TextString`PackagePrivate`fmtReal]

(*
   fmtReal[r_] := FromCharacterCode@...
*)
```

**Patch**

If we are willing to apply an unsanctioned patch ourselves, we can fix the bug:

```
Dataset;

Dataset`ImportExport`PackagePrivate`txt[r_Real | r_Rational] :=
  GeneralUtilities`TextString`PackagePrivate`fmtReal[r];

dat = Dataset[<| "A" -> 1.0, "B"-> 2.0 |>];
ExportString[dat, "CSV"]

(*
   "A",1.
   "B",2.
*)
```

Note that this patch must be applied after the dataset packages have been auto-loaded.  The otherwise apparently useless expression `Dataset;` forces the auto-loading to happen.

Comment: Thanks. I have also submitted a bug report.

Comment: @WReach I also get this error but the Stack Trace just shows error....

Comment: @SumNeuron Yes, the stack trace does not show much.  Try wading through the output given by `Select[UpValues[Dataset], Not@*FreeQ[ExportString]]` and ``TracePrint[
 Dataset`ImportExport`PackagePrivate`datasetExportString[dat, "CSV"]]``.  Debugging system internals is tricky (especially `Dataset`), but alas a meaty discussion of the techniques will not fit into comment boxes :D